# python simple help (NameError: name is not defined)

Tags: python-3.x

Whenever I run this is get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 130, in <module>
    while is_playing_cg:
NameError: name 'is_playing_cg' is not defined
```

I want the user to be able to press 1 or 2 to select which game mode to use and then once pressed it starts. I don't know why it's doing this. Whenever it's fixed it should run through just fine.

### New edit

Now it just loops and says 1 or 2 over and over again.

```
import random

is_playing_cg = False
is_playing_hg = False

def game_select_screen():
    
    #Game Select Screen
    print("""
    ._________________________________.
    |                                 |
    |  ~ Welcome To Guess-A-Number ~  |
    |               ~~~               |
    |     ~ Press 1  OR  Press 2 ~    |                   
    |     You ^ Guess | PC ^ Guess    |
    |_________________________________|""")                               
   
    selecting = True
   
    while selecting:
        
        print()
        game_mode = input("1 OR 2: ")
    
        try:
            int(game_mode)
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not a Number.")
        else:
            
            game_mode = int(game_mode)

        if game_mode == 1:
            is_playing_hg = True
            
        elif game_mode == 2:
            is_playing_cg = True
            

    
             
#Defining Random Number for human guess
def play_human_guess():
    num = random.randint (1,10)
    print()
    print("Im Thinking of a Number 1 Through 10.")
    print("You Have 3 Chances.")
    chances = 3
    game_fisnished = False
    
    #Game is playing (Human Guesses)
    while not game_fisnished:
            guess = input("> Take A Guess: ")
             
            #Accept only numbers
            try:                   
                int(guess)
            except ValueError:
                print("This is not a Number.")
            else:
                
                guess = int(guess) 
                if guess < num:
                    chances -=1
                    if chances == 0:
                        print()
                        print("Sorry You Guessed Too Many Times.")
                        game_fisnished = True
                    elif chances !=0:
                        print()
                        print("You Guessed Too Low. ("+str(chances)+") Chance(s) Remaining.")
                elif guess > num:
                    chances -=1
                    if chances == 0:
                        print()
                        print("Sorry You Guessed Too Many Times.")
                        game_fisnished = True
                    elif chances !=0:
                        print()
                        print("You Guessed Too High. ("+str(chances)+") Chance(s) Remaining.")
                else:
                    print()
                    print("Congradulations, You Won!")
                    game_fisnished = True
                    
#Game Ended
def end():
    print()
    print("Thanks For Playing!")
    
    


#Setting up for computer guess    
def play_computer_guess():
    print()
    print("Pick a Number 1 Through 10")
    print("I Have 3 Chances to Guess Your Number.")
    chances = 3
    game_fisnished = False
    
    #Game is playing (Computer Guess)
    while not game_fisnished:
            guess1 = input("Is your number 5?")
            
    
    
    
    
                    
    
                   

    
#Show Game Select Screen    
game_select_screen()



while is_playing_cg:
    #Start Game
    selecting = False
    play_computer_guess()
    
    answer = input("""
Do You Want to Play Again? (y/n) : """)
    if answer == "n":
        is_playing_cg = False



 

while is_playing_hg:
    #Start Game
    selecting = False
    play_human_guess()
    
    answer = input("""
Do You Want to Play Again? (y/n) : """)
    if answer == "n":
        is_playing_hg = False
        
end()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `is_playing_cg` inside of a conditional statement at the top of your code.  So if that option is *not* selected, then when you get to the latter conditional statement, it has never heard of that variable.... and it is not defined in the namespace.  So you could either define it at the top and give it a default (False) or more better, because you only have 2 options, just use **one** variable to control the computer / human.

Here is a toy example:

```
selection = int(input('enter 1 for human, 2 for computer: '))

if selection == 1:
    human_play = True
elif selection == 2:
    human_play = False

else:
    # make some loop that asks for input again or such...
    pass

# later on...

if human_play:
    # ask human for input...

else:
    # have AI make turn


#if needed, you can also handle special cases like this:

if not human_play:
    # do something unique to computer turn ...
```

Additional info...

So you got bit by the *scope* of the variables in your update.  You are defining these variables inside of a function and when you put the defaults outside of the function, they are not in the same scope, so whatever you do inside the function is lost.  So, you need to change your function into something that returns the mode you want, and catch that in the function call like such:

```
def ... :
    # input ...

    if game_mode == 1:
        human_playing = True
        selecting = False
        
    elif game_mode == 2:
        human_playing = False
        selecting = False

    return human_playing   # this will return T/F back to the function call
```

And then later:

```
#Show Game Select Screen    
human_playing = game_select_screen()

while not human_playing:
    #Start Game
    selecting = False
    play_computer_guess()
    
    answer = input("""
Do You Want to Play Again? (y/n) : """)
    if answer == "n":
        is_playing_cg = False

while human_playing:
    #Start Game
```

This (above) works for me, but there are still other logic errors popping up!  :)  Have fun

Comment: I added                                                                                                                      is_playing_cg = False and 
is_playing_hg = False                                                                                                           to the top and now whenever I say 1 or 2 it just  gives me my ending prompt message "thanks for playing!" and then it quits.

Comment: That should do it.  :)

Comment: why is it ending prematurely?

Comment: darn good question.  Would need to see your edit...  so, edit your code above and just add to it at the bottom and just pop in a comment above it for "revision 1".  Also, you can only "accept" one answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable is_playing_cg is only available in the "block" that creates it.
Block is function / loop / if statement / etc.
In your program you need to initialize the variable globally so you can call them in multiple functions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This particular error is probably there because you have not defined `is_playing_cg` as global before using it in your function `game_select_screen`. Simply put `global is_playing_cg` at the start of your `game_select_screen` function to tell python you want to use the global variable instead of creating a scoped variable.